# JSHint with ECMAScript6: method is not defined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jshint

I'm implementing a client-side application using ECMAScript6 and use [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) for static code analysis. I often use the following pattern in my code:

```
class MyClass {

    constructor() {
        //This is how I would like to call myMethod
        myMethod();

        //This is how I should call myMethod to make JSHint analysis pass
        this.myMethod();
    }

    myMethod(){
        //Implementation
    }
}
```

My primary language is Java so I expect that simply calling **myMethod()** should be ok. However without adding **this** to method call I'm getting "'myMethod' is not defined" warning from JSHint. My questions are:

1. Is it correct to make calls without **this** in such situation? (e.g. in PHP you always need to add **$this->** to non-static method call)
2. If that's correct to make calls **without this** is there any way (any **.jshintrc** flag) to turn off this warning in JSHint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is and never was correct in JavaScript. Methods always need to be called on a receiver explicitly to [make `this` work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/1048572), and they need to be referred to using property access notation because *methods are just functions on properties* in javascript. They're not available as functions in the scope of your other methods. [It's the same for properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13418980/1048572), btw.

JsHint is right here, and there's no reason to turn that warning off. Even if that may possible, executing your program in spite of that would just make it not work.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you provided the identifier `myMethod` isn't defined, but the inherited property *myMethod* of instances of `MyClass` is defined.

If you define `myMethod` as a *Function* under a closure which isn't available elsewhere then you can access as it in the form you desire

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function myMethod() {
        //Implementation
    }

    class MyClass {
        constructor() {
            myMethod();
        }
    }
    return MyClass;
}());
```

I don't get to write much ES6 so I'm not sure if putting the `function myMethod` inside `MyClass`'s definition is a *SyntaxError*

Please note however that `this` is required to reference your specific instance of `MyClass`, so you'll probably need to use it somewhere if you want `MyMethod` to act on the instance.

```
function myMethod(obj) {...}
// ...
        myMethod(this);
```

---

If you read the [**MDN's description of `class`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

> *JavaScript classes* are introduced in *ECMAScript 6* and are **syntactical sugar** over *JavaScript's* existing *prototype-based inheritance*. The class syntax is **not** introducing a new object-oriented inheritance model to *JavaScript*. JS classes provide a much **simpler and clearer syntax** to create objects and dealing with inheritance.

This is saying using `class` is just shorthand for the old way of doing it, not a new model, so it may be easier to think of what your current code would look like if written in *ES5*,

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
        this.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    MyClass.prototype = Object.create(null);
    MyClass.prototype.constructor = function () {
        myMethod(); // referenceError
        this.myMethod(); // works
    };
    MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function () {
        //Implementation
    };
    return MyClass;
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it correct to make calls without this in such situation? (e.g. in
>   PHP you always need to add $this-> to non-static method call)

No, it is not. You always have to specify the receiver of the method.

> If that's correct to make calls without this is there any way (any
>   .jshintrc flag) to turn off this warning in JSHint?

JSHint returns  "'myMethod' is not defined" warning correctly as there is not function called `myMethod` in the scope of the constructor.